# How to start and stop a MYSQL DB in Windows8

Tags: mysql, windows-8, mysql-workbench

I have installed twice MYSQL with an MSI Package on my Windows8 Workstation and I am unable to stop and start the DB over the MySQL Workbench. 
After installed the DB is started, but after booting the maschine the DB is not able to start again. I configured as a service, but in the services.msc It is not enabled to start the service.

How can this elementary thing be done ?

[image]

Comment: Are you using anything on port 80. Like Skype. While booting system skype is running/logged in with 80 port then MySQL will not up.  Please check

Comment: No. At install time I have also no conflict with ports. the db is running after installation.

Comment: By `MIS` you probably mean `msi`, right? Where did you download that from? Can you try with the normal MySQL Windows installer instead (get it from https://dev.mysql.com).

Comment: Thanks.I'll try. Yes you are right. I meant msi.